# How to make search engines understand website sections and tags?

Tags: seo, microdata, tags, structured-data

I have a website to sell products. It basically divides the products based on tags. For Example; if you access tag page for "iPhone", the website will display links to "iPhone 6 plus", "iPhone 4s","iPhone headset" etc..

My question is, How can I tell Google if the current page is a product page or tag "which I think is better for the user"?

My current URL schema is like the following:

```
For product: http://domain.tld/product_id/producat_name
For tag:  http://domain.tld/tags/tag_name

For product: http://example.com/1234/iphone 4s case
For tag:  http://example.com/tags/iphone
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the Schema.org vocabulary, you could use two [WebPage](http://schema.org/WebPage) sub-types:

- [ItemPage](http://schema.org/ItemPage) for a product.

  > A page devoted to a single item, such as a particular product or hotel.
- [CollectionPage](http://schema.org/CollectionPage) for a tag/category page.